# how to generate a report with some filter criteria in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, filter, report

I have a requirement for a report to determine which account number goes with a specific auto VIN.
The report requires some search or filter criteria that are similar to “Like” in t-sql.  For example, if a person looks for a VIN that ends with “231Z9” then he/she needs something to filter the VIN column, “VIN Like ‘%231Z9%’ “, to see if there are any match.
It also requires a filter by customer first name and customer last name. Lastly,
filters should not be embedded in the sql and need to be “OR” and not “AND” when being applied.
Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try using a parameter which will be part of a LIKE in your query?

Answer (score 0):

Write a stored proc that would return you the result data set for the report. To the stores procedure give parameters that can be viewed on the SSRS report and can  be embedded in the SQL.

To specify the same parameters for the report you can use the Report parameters options in SSRS

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a text variable for VIN
2. Create a text variable for FirstName
3. Create a text variable for LastName
4. Set up a dataset with the predicate

   ```
   Select (things)
   from (object)
   Where VIN like '%' + @VIN + '%' or
        FirstName like '%' + @FirstName + '%' or
        LastName like '%' + @LastName + '%'
   ```

Comment: Hi djangojazz, thanks a lot for the suggestion.   Here is what I have done so far                                               CREATE PROCEDURE Account_VIN_Lookup
VIN int,
FirstName varchar(50),
LastName varchar(50)
As
Begin
select (my columns) from (my tables) Where VIN like '%' + VIN + '%' or FirstName like '%' + FirstName + '%' or LastName like '%' + LastName + '%' . I dont think this is going to work since I haven't   not referred my varibales to the column. would you mind teaching me. thanks

Comment: I would just stick with a select I gave you substituting my (things) with your columns you want and the (object) with your table, view, or table function.  Adding another layer of complexity with teaching proc creation is overkill IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming by "filters should not be embedded in the SQL" you mean that the criteria must be parameterized, not hard-coded.  Stored procedures are good for that.

If you create a parameterized stored procedure that retrieves the data you want, set up a DataSet in a new SSRS report that uses that stored procedure as the source.  Report parameters will automatically be generated to correspond to the stored procedure parameters.  You can edit the report parameters (for user-friendly labels, to control whether they are optional or required, etc.)

This is assuming that your report will be accessed over the web.  You actually have a lot more options available if your report will be part of a client app (as opposed to a web app).